# Syntax error in Prepared statement while inserting into db

Tags: java

Hi I am trying insert data into the database using prepared statement but I am getting syntax error could u please help

```
public boolean SignUp(String last_name, String first_name,String email, String password,String confirm_password,String phone){



        Connect connect = new Connect();
        Connection conn = connect.Connection();

        java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        //NULL is the column for auto increment
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, last_name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, first_name);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, email);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, password);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, confirm_password);
        preparedStatement.setString(6, phone);

        int rs = preparedStatement.executeUpdate(insertQuery);

        conn.close();
```

}

here is the error message

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
```

Comment: You have 6 parameters in the prepared statement but only 5 set, could that be it?

Comment: You have 5 `?` marks and you are just setting 5 parameters.

Comment: Are you sure you're inputting the correct data types into the table?  Are you sure that's the correct number of parameters?

Comment: I had missed posting that earlier-- I have edited that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the statement to list the columns explicitly, and drop `NULL` from the list of values.

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users"
+  " (last_name, first_name, email, password, confirm_password, phone)"
+  " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

This way your insert statement is no longer dependent on the order of columns in your `users` table, and is also immune to addition of columns to the table.

Note that although this design is probably OK for a toy or an education system, but in a real production system storing password in a table is very dangerous. Storing `confirm_password` is rather unusual, too: normally your system checks that `password` is the same as `confirm_password`, and then inserts a salted password hash and a salt into the table.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight- Same error persists however the below one works

Comment: `String insertquery = "INSERT INTO details VALUES(NULL,('" + last_name
     + "'),('" + first_name + "'),('" + email + "'),('" + password
     + "'),('" + confirm_password + "'),('" + phone + "'))";`

Comment: @Srikanth They are inserting into different tables (`details` vs. `users`). Is this intentional?

Comment: I hate to hard code this way, for moment prepared statement is giving an error.

Comment: @Srikanth This is very strange, it is supposed to work. Try retyping the `values(?,?,?,?,?,?)` part, to make sure the `?` and ',' characters are the correct ASCII characters, not look-alike equivalents from other encodings.

Comment: Also thanks for the suggestion, I removed the column confirm_password, It's for an education purpose so I am retaining the password in the database without encryption

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer :)

Use preparedStatement.execute() instead of executeUpdate(sql). You have already set the sql and params - the new setting in executeUpdate(sql) overrides the bind.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, not I'm not certain.  But if one of the fields is autoincrement, then I don't think you need to insert it.  Try taking out that NULL....